# How can I separate out each bit from a byte?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# (and C in general for that matter) I'm getting a byte value returned from an external source that represents the states of 8 input pins on the port of an IO device so I get a value of 0-255 representing the binary pattern present on the port.

How can I strip out the individual bits and set them as bool vars, so doing something like this:

```
if (inputBuffer[1] == 1)
{
     IO.Input0 = true;
     IO.Input1 = false;
     IO.Input2 = false;
     IO.Input3 = false;
     IO.Input4 = false;
     IO.Input5 = false;
     IO.Input6 = false;
     IO.Input7 = false;
}
```

I'm probably overexplaining what I'm trying to achieve but thought this gives the best example although highly impractical, how can I better achieve this to set the variables based on a byte value of 0-255.

Comment: C# and C may look superficially similar by name and by some of their syntax, but I wouldn't group them together. C# and Java probably share more than do C# and C. IMO the C# name is just a clever Microsoft marketing ploy.

Comment: @DAB Right, because `ISO/IEC 23270:2006` just doesn't have quite the same ring to it. `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a bitwise-and (`&`). Assuming `Input0` represents the least significant bit:

```
IO.Input0 = (inputBuffer & 0x01) == 0x01;
IO.Input1 = (inputBuffer & 0x02) == 0x02;
IO.Input2 = (inputBuffer & 0x04) == 0x04;
IO.Input3 = (inputBuffer & 0x08) == 0x08;
IO.Input4 = (inputBuffer & 0x10) == 0x10;
IO.Input5 = (inputBuffer & 0x20) == 0x20;
IO.Input6 = (inputBuffer & 0x40) == 0x40;
IO.Input7 = (inputBuffer & 0x80) == 0x80;
```

---

You can also implement an extension method like the following:

```
public static bool IsBitSet(this byte b, int bit)
{
    if(bit < 0 || bit > 7)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bit must be between 0 and 7");

    byte bitToCheck = (byte)(0x01 << bit);

    return (b & bitToCheck) == bitToCheck;
}
```

Which you could then call like:

```
IO.Input4 = inputBuffer.IsBitSet(4);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a bitmask and the `&` operator to figure this out

```
byte b = 100;

if (b & 1 == 1) { } // bit 1 is set
if (b & 2 == 2) { } // bit 2 is set
if (b & 4 == 4) { } // bit 3 is set
...
```

Comment: Before your edit, you had `if(b&1) { } //bit 1 is set`, but you have now edited it and it is now correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think a self written class can help. Class could contain the 8 bits and the constructor takes a byte. In the constructor you can calculate the single bits.

```
public class myByte
{
    bool    Input0 = false;
    bool    Input1 = false;
    bool    Input2 = false;
    bool    Input3 = false;
    bool    Input4 = false;
    bool    Input5 = false;
    bool    Input6 = false;
    bool    Input7 = false;        

    public myByte(byte b)
    {
        //written by Ic.
        Input0 = b & 0x01 == 0x01;
        Input1 = b & 0x02 == 0x02;
        Input2 = b & 0x04 == 0x04;
        Input3 = b & 0x08 == 0x08;
        Input4 = b & 0x10 == 0x10;
        Input5 = b & 0x20 == 0x20;
        Input6 = b & 0x40 == 0x40;
        Input7 = b & 0x80 == 0x80;
    }
    ... //getter setter ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
int x= inputBuffer[1];

bit1 = ((x>>7)&1==1);
bit2 = ((x>>6)&1==1);
bit3 = ((x>>5)&1==1);
bit4 = ((x>>4)&1==1);
bit5 = ((x>>3)&1==1);
bit6 = ((x>>2)&1==1);
bit7 = ((x>>1)&1==1);
bit8 = (x&1==1);
```

To get 1st bit from say 11101110 value you need to right shift first bt 7 times and then doing AND operation with 1 will tell you whether the value is 1 or 0 and same solution applies for other bits as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is given to you in a Byte form and that each bit has been masked, then I would leave it as it is.  Converting them to another type is unnecessary, it will be extra work for no benefit.  To get the correct bit, just use the bit mask pattern:

```
private bool GetMaskedBit(var inputBuffer, int mask)
{
    return (inputBuffer & mask) != 0;
}
```

This way you parse the buffer and the required bit you wanted, this will return whether the bit has been set or not.

Comment: Why not just `return (inputBuffer & mask) != 0`?

Comment: They needed to be converted to individual bool vars for each input as it simplifies stuff elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BitArray` class.

```
var bitArray = new BitArray(inputBuffer);
IO.Input1 = bitArray[byteIndex * 8 + 1];
```

Or

```
var bitArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { inputBuffer[1] });
IO.Input1 = bitArray[1];
```

You can also iterate it as a collection of Boolean values, and perform bitwise operation on the entire collection.

It's obviously not as performant as the other options offered here (cost of allocation) but it does provide a very neat API for bit calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is limited to a couple bytes you don't need to hardcode a whole slew of shifting constants. In fact, you don't even need to perform any sort of bit-masking, bit-shifting, dividing, or modulo-ing.

Just "pull" the bits out from above, MSB first, with a starting point threshold that's a power of 2 larger than the input range, double the input for each round, and simply subtract out the threshold whenever the value is at or above it, recording that as a "1" bit.

With the extra side benefit of also knowing the cumulative value at each level without ever performing a single right-shift or division. Don't worry, it wouldn't overflow the precision of the integer type at all

e.g. :

---

```
47829729304001 =>
```

---

```
1010111000000000111010000001100101110111000001 

MSB
```

---

```
1|2|5|10|21|43|87|174|348|696|1392|2784|5568|11136|22272|
44544|89089|178179|356359|712718|1425437|2850874|5701748|
11403496|22806992|45613984|91227968|182455937|364911875|
729823750|1459647500|2919295001|5838590002|11677180005|
23354360011|46708720023|93417440046|186834880093|373669760187|
747339520375|1494679040750|2989358081500|5978716163000|
11957432326000|23914864652000|47829729304001
```

---

```
  6                    1    3    6       110
 29            1   3   7   14   29     11101
 52        1   3   6  13   26   52    110100
 75     1  2   4   9  18   37   75   1001011

 98     1  3   6  12  24   49   98   1100010
121     1  3   7  15  30   60  121   1111001
144  1  2  4   9  18  36   72  144  10010000
167  1  2  5  10  20  41   83  167  10100111

190  1  2  5  11  23  47   95  190  10111110
213  1  3  6  13  26  53  106  213  11010101
236  1  3  7  14  29  59  118  236  11101100
```